# Not able to make seo friendly URL from php using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a problem in creating SEO friendly url actually I have two url rewritten one is working and other one is not. I dont know why? please help
My url is this

```
       http://localhost/quotesnew/author.php?authID=1
```

and I want it to be

```
       http://localhost/author.html
```

here is my code in .htaccess file

```
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /quotesnew/index.php?authchar=$1 [L]
      RewriteRule ^author\.html$ /quotesnew/author.php?authID=1 [L]
```

Comment: What is returning in authID and authchar?

Comment: i am not able to understand what you mean brother.

Comment: if you id is 1 then how this will be come `a_a_attanasio`?

Comment: now I changed the requirement. please tell me why my one url is working and other is not working.

Comment: it could become `author-1.html` or `/1/author.html`

Comment: ok that will also do......how can we make such url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^author/([^/]*)\.html$ /quotesnew/author.php?authID=$1 [L]
```

Now your url would be

```
http://localhost/author/1.html
```

Comment: but brother i have two url in .htaccess file as you can see above

Answer (score 0):

The [L] flag stops rewriting for this cycle. It therefore never reaches the second rule.